# Referencing Google Play Library Error

Tags: android, google-maps

This is happen to me when referencing google play library project to my another project. What kind of error is this :

[image: screenshot]

Of course, my project still error importing the Android Google Maps V2.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

I also tried the example provided from the samples folder and got force close with `maps` samples project. Whether these relate to my screenshot of error?

BTW, I am using real device with OS version 2.3.4 and internet connection of course. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of the time that means the path to the project is wrong

Comment: I am confused with this. I browse the correct library project folder, then I got green check and click Apply->OK. I check the class still error, then I open up reference library window again and got red cross like screenshot above. :(

Comment: means the Google Library Project not imported properly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put Google play library in same drive where you have kept your project... Then import Google play library into your workspace and add it to your project... Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 1):

I am already faced this problem. Below Steps worked for me.

1) import **Google Play Services Library**  to your workspace.

2) Reference it to your project.

3) Reference will be changed into Red color, that time simply remove your library and again import and Reference.Then it will work.

Note: Before doing these steps please delete your previous **Google Play Services library** and Download.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly reference the library from the sdk. Frist import Goople Play Services Library to your workspace then reference it to your project.